# How to use JavaScript variable in img src attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Below JavaScript function is called after selecting option from `<select>` tag.

```
function function1()
{
var country=document.getElementById('id1').value;
switch(country)
{
 case "India":
     logo="rupee.png";
     break;
 case "US":
     logo="dollar-logo.png";
     break;
 case "Britan":
      logo="yen.png";
      break;
}
```

Now i want to display flag of country according to selection has made..
Below is HTML file where i want to display image..

```
<td><img src="+logo+" width=30 height=30></td>
```

I also tried this one..

```
<td><img src="<%Eval(logo)%>" width=30 height=30></td>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("myimg").src = logo;` ?

Comment: By the way... You have no quotes around the `width` and `height` property. Is it not required?

Comment: yes it works... or u can take variable to store getElementById() and then usng variable.src to provide path..Thank you

Comment: @AndreasFurster Ya quotes is not compulsory..

Comment: @SwapnilKadam, ok! Learnt something new :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use

```
case "India":
     myImg.src="rupee.png";
     break;
case "US":
     myImg.src="dollar-logo.png";
     break;
case "Britan":
     myImg.src="yen.png";
     break;
```

where `myImg` is your image. In your current html, it is:

```
var myImg = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
```

Or you can add `id` attribute to your image (`<img id="logo" width=30 height=30>`), so you can use

```
var myImg = document.getElementById("logo");
```

(you should place `myImg` initialization at the beginning of the `function1()`)

Answer (score 2):

You can set attribute using JS

```
function function1()
   {
   var country=document.getElementById('id1').value;
    switch(country)
      {
      case "India":
      logo="rupee.png";
      break;
      case "US":
      logo="dollar-logo.png";
      break;
      }
    document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = logo;
   }
```